# Shiny application crashing on startup when supplied a public ip

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny application. It starts up fine when being set to my local ip, but when set to my public ip address, it gives me this error message:

```
Listening on http://publicip:port
Error in startServer(host, port, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) : 
  Failed to create server
Calls: runApp -> startApp -> startServer
Execution halted
```

I start it up with this script

```
library(shiny);
runApp("App", port=portNumber, host=getOption('shiny.host', "publicip"));
```

It doesn't seem to bind to my public ip when being set to localhost.  And yes, I have already port forwarded the port that I am using.

It is also being run from an ubuntu server on R version 3.3.0

Comment: You are obviously confusing shiny server and shiny application ( this is a kind of server). You are just launching a shiny application in server not a shiny server. Shiny server will be launched automatically once installed.

Comment: Okay, but do you have a solution to this question?  That information isn't really relevant to the question asked.

Comment: Thank you! very polite way to ask for a solution ! **The solution is to install shiny-server**. Shiny app is good to run application locally not to be exposed in internet/intranet.

Answer (score 1):

To host a server publicly, you use your private ip, not your public ip or localhost.

Use

```
192.168.x.x
```

Don't use

```
127.0.0.1
localhost
public ip (e.g. 12.34.56.78)
```